# Connecting to hbase instance from pyhon script using Docker

Tags: python, docker, hbase, happybase

I have a very simple python script using `happyase` connecting to a docker image of hbase

```
import happybase


def main():
    connection = happybase.Connection('hbase-docker', port=9090)
    print(connection.tables())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

i have used this docker container to get hbase running

https://hub.docker.com/r/dajobe/hbase/

using

```
docker pull dajobe/hbase
```

and then

```
docker run dajobe/hbase
```

but still no connection

`thriftpy2.transport.base.TTransportException: TTransportException(type=1, message="Could not connect to ('hbase-docker', 9090)")`

I have tried with different ports, but nothing seems to work..

I used `Docker ps` to verify, that the container is running.

```
b42a2dd58d1c        dajobe/hbase        "/opt/hbase-server"      35 seconds ago      Up 34 seconds       2181/tcp, 8080/tcp, 8085/tcp, 9090/tcp, 9095/tcp, 16010/tcp                       amazing_engelbart
```

Comment: How are you linking the containers?

Comment: I'm not linking the container in anyway yet... just run on localhost and running the python script in my file

Comment: The Hbase container is just runninbg, and my python script is not packated in any way

Comment: You've not expose port 9090 to the host, and service running on your host cannot resolve docker containers by name. Perhaps go over some more Docker networking basics or run the Python code in a container as well if you want to change nothing